# ¿Cómo insertar fecha automatica en C# y MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql

quisiera pedir asesoría soy nuevo en esto de la programación y estoy tratando de introducir la fecha por automático mediante un botón en C#.

Este es mi método para realizar insertar los datos:

```
        public void registrarIngreso(int id)
        {
            string nw = "NOW()";
            string cr = "CURDATE()";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Uid=root; Password=''; Database=papeleria_rosita; Port=3306");
            MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO registrtos(idTrabajador, fecha, hora) VALUES("+id+","+cr+","+nw+")");
            cm.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Ingreso registrado.");
        }
```

Y por aquí desde donde mando a instanciar dicho método:

```
            RegistroController ctrlRegistro = new RegistroController();
            int id = 15;
            ctrlRegistro.registrarIngreso(id);
```

Comment: El problema es que no inserta nada no?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: pero porque dos campos, de fecha y hora por separado, si defines la fecha este ya tiene la hora incluida

Comment: @LeandroTuttini , nunca esta ejecutando el comando ;).. vamos por partes...

Comment: Estas seguro de que la tabla se llama `registrtos` y no `registros`? Es posible que sea un error tipográfico? Te lanza alguna excepción que ayude a ver cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Realmente lo mejor en estos casos es que tu campo de fecha en la base de datos  tenga por defecto la fecha actual DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP para que en la inserción de tus datos lo omitas y por defecto mysql llenara ese campo por ti.

por ejemplo :

```
ALTER TABLE `appointment` CHANGE `created_dt` `created_dt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte... por favor mira [answer] y de paso hace el [tour]. Aunque esto podria ser una solucion, parece mas un comentario que una solucion al problema que tiene, que va mas alla de eso...

Answer (score 0):

Aconsejaria que tu codigo sea algo como esto

```
public void registrarIngreso(int id)
{
    string connstring = "server=localhost; Uid=root; Password=''; Database=papeleria_rosita; Port=3306";
    using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        con.Open();

        string query = "INSERT INTO registrtos (idTrabajador, fecha) VALUES (?id, ?fecha)";
        MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", id);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?fecha", DateTime.Now);

        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Ingreso registrado.");
}
```

Algunos puntos:

- Nunca ejecutas el insert ya que te falta el `ExecuteNonQuery()`
- Debes usar simpre parametros, no se concatenan NUNCA en un string los valores
- No necesitas dos campos separados para la fecha y la hora, si defines el campo domo datetime este incluye la hora, solo deja un campo

Comment: Pero no le estas explicando su problema.. solo le estas escribiendo el codigo :/

Comment: la explicacion esta en los puntos donde detallo lo que observo y debe cambiar